# What means "BP Bottom Temp"

Tags: dell-poweredge, dell-openmanage

I am administering a legacy Dell Poweredge 2650 Server. I am doing a routine maintenance check using Dell OpenManage Server Administrator.

When navigating to `System > Main System Chassis > Temperature` I am getting temp readings of different parts of the server. There are three abbreviations I do not understand. They are marked bold below:

- **BP** Bottom TEMP
- **ESM** CPU 1 TEMP
- ESM **Frt** I/O TE

MP

I googled the definitions but could not find what they mean. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Tried the Dell site?

Comment: Yes. Did not find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally these acronyms mean:

- BP => Backplane (see also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backplane)
- ESM => Embedded System Module (should be your DRAC)
- FRT => Front